# How to implement advanced validation rules in Laravel+lighthouse graphql?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Before switching to Lighthouse I used to have validation rules like this:

```
Rule::unique('users', 'name')->where('site_id', $this->route()->parameter('site')->id)->ignore($this->route()->parameter('user')->id),
```

So I need to select users with certain `site_id` before checking if user's name is unique. Now I have the following mutation:

```
updateUser(
    name: String! @rules(apply: ["App\\Rules\\UniqueUserName"])
): User! @update
```

But how should I provide `site_id` (`site_id` should be considered as read-only attribute) and how can I access it in my custom validation rule `UniqueUserName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex validation logic can be implemented by extending `ValidationDirective` class.

Then one can write rules in the `rules()` method just as it was in the laravel standard request validation. Arguments are available via `$this->args['site_id']`.

More info: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/security/validation.html#validate-fields

Comment: Using `$this->args['site_id]` results in an error with the following debugMessage: `"Cannot use object of type Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\Arguments\\ArgumentSet as array"`. It seems `$this->arg('site_id')` is better.